# Restore original string.h after accidental overwrite

Tags: c, header-file

I was reading the header files for c and by accident, i changed something (i deleted some stuff by accident) I closed out of sublime text editor, expecting it to ask me to save, but it saved automatically and now it is stuck like that.

Is there any way to undo what I just did?
The line that got changed was:

> extern char *y (char *__restrict __dest,
>   from this code:

```
 BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
/* Copy SRC to DEST.  */
extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
     __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
/* Copy no more than N characters of SRC to DEST.  */
extern char *y (char *__restrict __dest,
              const char *__restrict __src, size_t __n)
     __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));

/* Append SRC onto DEST.  */
extern char *strcat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
     __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
/* Append no more than N characters from SRC onto DEST.  */
extern char *strncat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src,
```

Im pretty sure that its not supposed to be a "y". Im pretty sure thats all i changed.
Can someone please help?

Comment: @WarrenYoung I wasn't running as root. something else I just noticed. I went to go make it strncpy and it asked for my password

Comment: I never gave my password though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference: reinstalling the appropriate package will restore the original file.

With Debian, having package `apt-file` installed, executing e.g. `apt-file find usr/include/string.h` will find what package deliver such file.

Then `apt-get --reinstall install libc6-dev` will reinstall (restore) the files of `libc6-dev` package (which includes `string.h`).

Answer (score 1):

From the comment and context, `y` is clearly `strncpy`. Simply change it back.